# exposing angularjs grid data from one controller into another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to push data from a link within my grid data UI, when you click the link, open a popup (which I do with a modal fine) however when the modal opens, I can't access any of the data that was defined in the other controller.

This snippet:

```
    <a href ng-click="grid.appScope[col.field](row.entity)">Popup</a>
```

Works fine, where it shows the col.field value, however I'd like to show data within the popup from grid.appScopecol.field in the popup - however that is another controller, how would I handle passing data from one controller to another within this format?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is just pass those data into angular `service` define a service like

```
angular.service('MyService', function() {
//if you want Object format or
this.controller1Data = {};

//if you want array format
this.controller1Data = {};

});
```

in your controller just pass the data into that service like

```
//In controller
MyService.controller1Data = //Pass the data to that service;
```

then in HTMl

```
<a href ng-click="//call that method()">Popup</a>
```